# DIV Games Studio (o DIV 2): ¿Existe un lugar oficial u objetivamente fiable en la web, o DIV está desatendido?

Tags: ide, motor-de-juego

Lo usé cuando surgió (se compraba en kioscos), y me resultaría cómodo usarlo ahora (aunque esté algo pasado o sea simple, ya que aun así es útil para muchas cosas). Pero investigar por Internet es un mareo y uno no sabe sobre su fiabilidad.

Es más fácil preguntarlo aquí y obtener una respuesta simple, objetiva, rápida, y con conocimiento suficiente.

La casa original era Hammer Technologies; luego pasó a otros propietarios y después ya no sé lo que sucedió.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Actualmente existen muchos frameworks o herramientas visuales muy sencillos como son Game Maker o Godot para hacer juegos sencillos. solo tienes que hacer una pequeña búsqueda por internet. Sobre DIV2, no se quepaso exactamente.

Comment: Gracias por los aportes. Naturalmente estoy al tanto de las numerosas posibilidades que hay, pero me sería cómodo usar DIV puesto que ya hice bastantes cosas con él. Veamos si alguien nos da alguna info más. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Un par de cosas más: no he visto la manera de que conste mi agradecimiento (será que no tengo todavía esa posibilidad, al ser novato). Y la otra: no he recibido aviso por eMail, y creo que lo tengo bien configurado aquí.